# Converse of 0/0 Type Stolz Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

One version of Stolz Theorem is that

Given two sequences $\{a_n\},\{b_n\}$, with $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$ and $\{b_n\}$ is strictly decreasing and its limit is also $0$. Then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{a_n-a_{n+1}}{b_n-b_{n+1}}=L<\infty$$
implies $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{a_n}{b_n}=L.$$

I want to find a counterexample for the converse statement, although I'm not so sure is there any counterexample.

I first assume $a_n/b_n$ has a limit and its limit is $L$, then $$\dfrac{a_n-a_{n+1}}{b_n-b_{n+1}}-\dfrac{a_n}{b_n}=\dfrac{a_n/b_n-a_{n+1}/b_{n+1}}{b_n/b_{n+1}-1}$$
If $\lim b_n/b_{n+1}\neq 1$, then it is easy to see that the inverse is also true. But if $b_n/b_{n+1}\to 1$, we have 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\cdot\dfrac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}=\dfrac LL=1$$
so if there is a counterexample, it must satisfy both $b_n/b_{n+1}\to 1$ and $a_n/a_{n+1}\to 1$. Being stricted the search domain, I'm still not able to work out a counterexample. Hence is there really a counterexample or the converse is indeed true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a counterexample, take

$$a_n = \frac{3}{n} - \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}, \quad b_n =\frac{3}{n} + \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2},$$

where $a_n, b_n \to 0$ and  $\frac{a_n}{b_n} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty.$

We have
$$a_{n+1} - a_n = \frac{-3}{n(n+1)} +(-1)^n\frac{2n^2 + 2n +1}{n^2(n+1)^2}, \\ b_{n+1} - b_n = \frac{-3}{n(n+1)} -(-1)^n\frac{2n^2 + 2n +1}{n^2(n+1)^2}$$

Note that $b_n$ is strictly decreasing since, clearly, $b_{n+1} -b_n <0$ when $n$ is even and when $n$ is odd

$$n^2 (n+1)^2 (b_{n+1}-b_n) = -3n^2 -3n + 2n^2 + 2n +1 = -n^2 - n + 1 < 0$$

However,

$$c_n =\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1} - b_n} = \frac{-3 + (-1)^n\left(2+ \frac{1}{n^2+n}\right)}{-3 - (-1)^n\left(2+ \frac{1}{n^2+n}\right)}$$

does not converge, with $\limsup_{n \to \infty} c_n = 5$ and $\liminf_{n \to \infty}c_n = 1/5$.

Comment: Thank you! This example is truly genius.

Comment: @kelvinhong方: You're welcome.